# 7zip archive is too large when using -x

Tags: 7-zip

I am compressing a dir into a zip, and use several -x switches.

```
7z a -tzip -x!.\test1.gadget\.git\* -x!.\test1.gadget\.gitignore test1.zip  .\test1.gadget\*  

7-Zip [64] 9.22 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2011 Igor Pavlov  2011-04-18
Scanning

Creating archive test1.zip

Compressing  .git\COMMIT_EDITMSG
Compressing  .git\config
Compressing  .git\description
Compressing  .git\HEAD
```

However, instead of the ~20k I expect the zip file to be (based on the size of the desired content), the zip file is ~120k.  When inspecting the zip file, none of the excluded content (the .git dir) is present.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks...

Comment: Err… so when you list the contents of the archive lose bad files are not there?

Comment: Correct -- archive is still the size I expect it would be if the excluded files were present.

Comment: How do you estimate the expected archive size?

Comment: Try putting the files to include first, followed by those you want excluded.

Comment: @gronostaj: size of zip before trying to exclude.

Comment: Thanks, folks, for the help, this seems to work as desired:  7z a -tzip test.zip test.gadget\* -x!test.gadget\.git\ -x!test.gadget\.idea\
 -x!test.gadget\.gitignore

Comment: @Number8: Add that as an answer below instead of a comment that people may miss.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, folks, for the help, this seems to work as desired:
 7z a -tzip test.zip test.gadget* -x!test.gadget.git\ -x!test.gadget.idea\ -x!test.gadget.gitignore